# How to fix WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) font on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, terminal, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My WSL font keep change to default font(not even mono fonts!) when I launch another utilities(man,vi,nano,etc...)

I checked the "Defaults" and "Properties" of WSL and set the fonts to "Consolas". But everytime a launch another utilities it fallback to the default font...

Googled a little bit still no idea what's going on or anyway i can configure for this.

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to be mentioned in two bug reports:

- [Font in WSL Console window changes to Raster Fonts when Running a powershell.exe command with Consolas font #367](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/367)
- [Windows 10 1809/19H1/20H1 breaks Powershell's console settings. Keeps opening with raster fonts. #280](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/280).

There is no clear response from the developers about the problem.
Some explanation is given in the second link:

> It was only detected in 1809 because the default font for the console
> was Consolas. Prior to that, I believe it was Lucida Console? And the
> code worked the same way for that font. My understanding of that code
> (which has been there since forever and prior to my team on the
> PowerShell Team) is that in the Windows sources, we only have one
> shortcut used for PowerShell and that shortcut defines the default
> font. So when the default font was changed, East Asian users
> complained as their glyphs weren't being rendered since the font
> doesn't support it. So this code detects that the font and locale
> aren't compatible and switches it to one that will render.
>
> I'm hesitant on making any changes in Windows PowerShell as even
> seemingly small changes like this lead to unexpected regressions.

A workaround was suggested in the first link (which didn't work for
everyone), was to change `FaceName` to the font used in WSL Console
in the registry at keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_SysWOW64_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe
```

My value for `FaceName` is currently `Lucida Console`.

In the first link it was remarked also:

> Observation: if you have a BAT file where you call powershell
> script.ps1 two times the second call resets font to raster.
>
> Inserting chcp 437 between the calls helps.

The conclusion is that this was always broken, but the problem is
only now appearing because Windows version 1809 changed the default
font to Consolas. Changing the default font in `FaceName` to either
Lucida Console or Consolas might help, not to solve the bug but
perhaps to hide it a bit.
Adding `chcp` commands before the call to PowerShell might also help.

The only real solution would be if Microsoft fixed the bug, but it
seems that the code involved is rather old, so that the current
PowerShell team is hesitant about modifying it.

Comment: Based on numerous examples, there is a strong possibility, when Microsoft replaces PowerShell 5.1 with the current PowerShell Core this behavior could possibly be fixed.  However, the chances of it being fixed on previous versions of Windows, other than Windows 11 is extremely unlikely.  Even then because Microsoft clearly considers Windows Terminal the future, since it's the default terminal in Windows 11, there is a less than significant possibility this font behavior will never be fixed.  Great answer by the way!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to provide a bit of an orthogonal solution.  I don't know why your font is being reset.  There's probably a very simple reason, and if someone posts it, you should accept their answer.

But I propose that it's not worth troubleshooting.

The "default" terminal that WSL uses (for now) is the legacy "Windows Console Host", which is over 20 years old, iirc.  Microsoft has, in the last few years, released [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/terminal) as its replacement.  It is:

- A feature-rich, tabbed terminal interface for WSL, PowerShell, CMD, and any Windows console application.
- Available for installation from the Microsoft Store.
- Open-source ([Github link](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal))
- Actively developed with (currently) regular new feature releases
- Available to set as the default Terminal in Windows 11, thereby replacing Console Host.

My personal recommendation for anyone having any sort of issue with Windows Console Host is simply to upgrade to Windows Terminal.